# on Scrolling Custom layout hide or show

Tags: android

I am working on an app and getting stuck on some code. Actually I am using search layout inside a fragment and on scrolling `RecyclerView` I have to hide or show that layout. And I used on scrolling listener for that but on translation it is showing blank space. You can see my code and after that I used scaling but I did not get any expected result.

```
public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView view, int dx, int dy) {

    if (dy > 0) {
        if (!up)
            scaleView(searchLayout, searchLayout.getScaleY(), .0f);
        up=true;
        down=false;
    }
    else if (dy < 0) {
        if(!down)
        scaleView1(searchLayout, .0f, searchLayout.getScaleY());
        up=false;
        down=true;
    }

}

public void scaleView(View v, float startScale, float endScale) {

    Animation anim = new ScaleAnimation(
            1f, 1f, // Start and end values for the X axis scaling
            startScale, endScale, // Start and end values for the Y axis scaling
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f, // Pivot point of X scaling
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, endScale); // Pivot point of Y scaling
    anim.setFillAfter(true); // Needed to keep the result of the animation
    anim.setDuration(1000);
    anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            searchLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    v.startAnimation(anim);

}
public void scaleView1(View v, float startScale, float endScale) {
    Animation anim = new ScaleAnimation(
            1f, 1f, // Start and end values for the X axis scaling
            startScale, endScale, // Start and end values for the Y axis scaling
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f, // Pivot point of X scaling
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f); // Pivot point of Y scaling
    anim.setFillAfter(true); // Needed to keep the result of the animation
    anim.setDuration(1000);
    anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            searchLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    v.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

I'm getting blank space on scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code into your scrollview and control the view according to the dependant view in your view

Use Nestedscroll view around your Recyclerview

```html
 scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {
               

                Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
                scrollView.getHitRect(scrollBounds);
                if (yourView.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
                                                                     // is your dependant view is in visible bounds
                    searchBar.setVisibility("Visibility.GONE");
                    
                                                                      //your animation

                } else {
                    searchBar.setVisibility("Visibility.VISISBLE");
                    
                                                                       //your animation


                }

            }
        });
```